# What is the difference between a Grunt Task and a Grunt Plugin?

Tags: gruntjs

GruntJS's documentation is pretty thrifty. There's a small section on creating a task, and one on creating a plugin.

If I want to create a new thing (rather than using an existing thing like `jslint`) then am I creating a task or a plugin?

Comment: I've never read the GruntJS documentation, but understanding this common words I'm pretty sure that a task execute a plugin. If there is no plugin, there is no task.

Comment: Tasks can exist without plugins. Plugins are useless without tasks. Gruntfile.js works the same way as a plugin so it could itself be considered the `default` plugin.

Comment: Well, a plugin could be useful without tasks if you were manually calling helper functions in it or something from another plugin.

Answer (score 3):

A plugin is just a convention for creating reusable tasks and publishing them to npm. If you don't need to publish them to npm then you can do the same with

```
grunt.registerTask('alphabetize', 'description', function(arr) {
    /// ...
});
```

You would write a task whether you create it in the gruntfile.js or encapsulate it in a plugin. In a plugin it would just encapsulate that task

```
module.exports(function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('alphabetize', 'description' function(arr) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Think of a plugin as just another `Gruntfile.js` that's located in a different folder with it's own `package.json`. It does the same thing as the `Gruntfile.js` but in a more reusable way.

Comment: OK, so if I want to write something to, for example, alphabetise a text file, what I would be writing would be a plugin.  When I _use_ this plugin in the `gruntfile.js` then this is a task?

Comment: OK... nearly got it.  Plugins can be used by `NodeJS` via the `require()` statements (?), when it's like this we call a task a plugin.

Comment: Not quite. A task is defined using `grunt.registerTask()` or `grunt.registerMultiTask()`. A plugin is just another gruntfile that can also (optionally) register its own tasks.

Comment: and yes, grunt will use `require()` to include plugins just like it uses `require()` to include the gruntfile.

Comment: OK... the things sitting in the NPM registry are tasks.  Plugins are.. predefined groups of tasks defined via a `gruntfile.js`.